# Where does the image in gitbox originate from?

Tags: git, github, gitbox

I use [Gitbox](http://www.gitboxapp.com/) as my version control tool on MAC OSX. When using the app, I see an odd image next to the author name. For example, this is the image I am referring to:

[image]

( This image is just an example. I am not showing the actual photo I see. The concept is the same )

The interesting part is that I was under the impression that the image should be fetched from "GitHub", but it seems it is fetched elsewhere as my GitHub image is significantly different. The photo is odd enough that I am confused wrt to it's origin.

Where is this image loaded from in Gitbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fetched from [Gravatar](https://gravatar.com). You should be able to sign in there to change your picture.